# CoreData Lightweight migrations error when integrating RestKit and MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, database-migration, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord along with RestKit but I'm having trouble performing lightweight migrations.

I've followed [this example](https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord/) but got a `CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null)` after [this line is executed](https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord/blob/master/RKMagicalRecord/RKMRAppDelegate.m#L30).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for my problem was to perform the "good and old" Clean on XCode.